# Python: Determine Missing Line

Tags: python, list, data-extraction

Take for example a short file consisting of these lines:

```
Apple = 1
Pear = 1
Orange = 2
;
Orange = 3
Pear = 1
;
Apple = 1
Pear = 1
Orange = 1
```

What I did was to readline the text file, and put `Apple`, `Orange` and `Pear` into their respective lists such as:

```
Orange = [ 2,3,1 ]
Pear = [ 1,1,1 ]
```

I used `line.count('Apple')==1` to identify that the current line in the text file is a fruit and then append the value after `=` to the list.

As you can see, the second section is missing `Apple`. I want the list to be:

```
Apple = [ 1,'-',1]
```

Whenever the line does not show a fruit, the list should append `-` to indicate it.

My question is, how then can I do it ie. to determine that a section is missing a fruit name and then to append `-` to it.

Comment: `Apple = [ 1,-,1]` is not valid python. I assume you meant to use strings.

Comment: @Tadeck I have no idea how to determine the missing line of fruit in the text file. I have some idea of using the ";" at the end of each section to to let Python know that if at the end of the section the fruit name is not being appended to the list, then append "-" to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep an array with all the fruit names found in a section. When you encounter a semicolon you check for each fruit if its name exists in the array and append a '-' if it does not, then you clear the array and continue with the next section.

Comment: I got your idea. Yah this is something I had in mind. I will give it a try. Thx

Comment: If the line is missing in the first section this isn't going to work. If you want to do this, you must either have a complete list of fruit from the start, or you must keep all the "sections" until the very end and then check each one if it contains all fruit.

Comment: I assumed that he has a complete list of fruits from the start, since he named his variables after them.

Comment: Yah actually I have a certain fruits that will be/should be in the text file. So the first section problem should be fine right

Comment: @PokerProf: [you could use all names from the file](http://ideone.com/ScJHN) if you didn't know them already.

Comment: LOL I actually had the right idea in mind already but thanks to Michael for making it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if line.count('Apple')==1:
    Apple.append(str(number))
else:
    Apple.append('-')
```

Comment: I tried this. I'm afraid the result will be a lot of '-' in the list since every other line that doesn't contain Apple will be the else case!

Comment: you may try:
`if 'Apple' not in ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']:`

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import takewhile

d = defaultdict(list)
valid_fruits = set(['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'])

with open('data.txt') as f:
    while True:
        fruits = dict(takewhile(lambda x: x[0] != ';',
                                (line.rstrip().split(' = ') for line in f)))
        if not fruits:
            break
        for fruit in valid_fruits:
            if fruit in fruits:
                d[fruit].append(int(fruits[fruit]))
            else:
                d[fruit].append('-')

print d
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Orange': [2, 3, 1], 'Pear': [1, 1, 1], 'Apple': [1, '-', 1]})
```

Comment: Nice one. Though I think I have found a much simpler solution in the above that should fit well into my current script. Thanks.